# How to get methods in source order

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have a custom annotation that I want to use at runtime to display object properties. I would like them to appear in source code order but reflection does not guarantee any particular order for `Class.getMethods()`.

Is there a way, either via reflection or via annotation processing, to get the methods in source order (at least per class if multiple levels of inheritance are involved)?

As an example, say I had an interface `Property`

```java
package test;

public @interface Property {
    public String name();
}
```

and a class using that annotation

```java
package test;

public class MyObject {
    @Property(name = "First")
    public void getFirst() {}

    @Property(name = "Another")
    public void getAnother() {}
}
```

I'd like to reliably get the property "First" before the property "Another".

I know I can add an ordering property to my annotation and sort on that but I have a lot of classes that would need to be updated if that is required so I'm looking for a generic method to achieve this without modifying individual annotations.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way, but even if there is, this seems like a bad idea for maintainability, because someone else could rearrange the code for readability and never suspect that rearranging the code could change the program's behavior.  If you do find a way to accomplish this, I hope you do it as a short-term quick fix hack only, and change it to a real solution later.

Comment: @ajb, it is possible during annotation processing, but not via reflection (as far as I know). I agree with your concern about relying on source code ordering, but for legacy reasons we need to support this for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is not possible via reflection unless you are willing and able to change the original source to impose an order via an additional annotation or attribute of an existing annotation.

It is possible, however, during annotation processing. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getEnclosedElements%28%29) for `TypeElement.getEnclosedElements()`] indicates that

> the list of enclosed elements will be returned in the natural order for the originating source of information about the type. For example, *if the information about the type is originating from a source file, the elements will be returned in source code order* [emphasis added].

To make this available at runtime, you need to process the methods with the annotations and store somewhere that will be accessible at runtime (e.g a generated resource file).

Answer (score 2):

If you collect the annotations into a`List<Property>` you can order the `List` like any other collection using `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)`.  The main issue is there is no natural order to how the annotations should be ordered, so you will need to define this order.  I have defined the order via a `List` which is used in the comparator.

```
public class MyObject {

    @Property(name = "First")
    public void getFirst() {
    }

    @Property(name = "Another")
    public void getAnother() {
    }

    @Property(name = "Last")
    public void getLast() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method[] methods = MyObject.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();

        for(Method method: methods){
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)){
                properties.add(method.getAnnotation(Property.class));
            }
        }

        for(Property property:properties){
            System.out.println(property.name());
        }

        Collections.sort(properties, new Comparator<Property>(){

            List<String> order = Arrays.asList("Last", "First", "Another");

            @Override
            public int compare(Property arg0, Property arg1) {
              //Compare only considers the sign of result.  
              return (order.indexOf(arg0.name()) - order.indexOf(arg1.name()));
            }

        });

        for(Property property:properties){
            System.out.println(property.name());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @KevinBowersox, but I am looking for something generic based on source code order. Your solution requires specific knowledge of the ordering to be added for each class.

Comment: @RangiKeen I change my answer to `Its not possible`